# Osx - users and GUI

Tags: macos, kernel, osx-server

My question is very simple.

How does OSX understands that this special process needs to make output to special terminal? Can we change it?

For example, is it possible to run process via ssh connection (without GUI) and make some system call, and this process will start using OSx GUI

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand your question, but I suspect you maybe have a look at the "expect" tool, which allows you to start some connection and then let the user continue after you have established the connection. Try:

```
man expect
```

in a terminal window.